# Retrieving XML attribute values using Python iterparse

Tags: python, xml-parsing, elementtree, xml-attribute, iterparse

I'm trying to find out how to retrieve XML attribute values using the cElementTree iterparse in Python (2.7). My XML is something like this:

```
<root>
  <record attr1="a" attr2="b" attr3="c" ... />
  <record attr1="x" attr2="y" attr3="z" ... />
  ...
</root>
```

My code is something like this:

```
context = ET.iterparse(sys.stdin, events=('start','end'))
context = iter(context)
event, root = context.next()

for event, elem in context:
    if event == 'end' and elem.tag == 'record':
        # get the attributes!! 
    elem.clear()
    root.clear()
```

I'm dealing with big data from stdin.
I'm not having any luck figuring this out. Could someone please tell how (optimal?) to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Oops, staring me in the face, sort of: http://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#element-objects

In summary:

```
elem.get('attr_name', default_value)
```

or,

```
for name, value in elem.items():
```

or,

```
elem.attrib() - dictionary
```

I should also add that it was necessary to modify the code posted in the question:

```
...
if event == 'start' and elem.tag == 'record':
...
```

Comment: the correct way to retrieve the dictionary is by invoking:
elem.attrib

The open brackets are not needed